# Using a Python function, how can I trigger the training function in train.py

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, yolo, yolov5, yolov8

I am currently using the command-line command to **train** my yolov5 model:
`python train.py --img 512 --batch 14 --epochs 5000 --data neurons.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt --cache ram`

However, I want to trigger the training process using the `train()` method in the `train.py` file. Here is the code I am using to run it as a subprocess:

```
subprocess.run(['python3.10',
                'yolov5/train.py',
                '--img',
                'weights/last_yolov5s_custom.pt',
                '--img',
                '512',
                '--batch',
                '14',
                '--epochs',
                '2',
                '--data',
                'neurons.yaml',
                '--weights',
                'yolov5s.pt',
                '--cache',
                'ram'])
```

I would like to know how to pass all the command-line parameters I am currently using to the train() function in the train.py file. The train() function expects a parameter called opt, which is a custom argparse object as shown in the **Extras**.

Here is the train() function definition in the train.py file:

```
def train(hyp, opt, device, callbacks):
    # Code implementation
```

The opt parameter is obtained from the parse_opt() function, which uses argparse for parsing the command-line arguments.

How can I  modify my code to trigger the training process using the train() method and pass the necessary command-line parameters?

#### Extras

opt object originated from the `main` method;

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    opt = parse_opt()
    main(opt)
```

Here is the `parse_opt()` method which is using `argparse` *parser*;

```
def parse_opt(known=False):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--weights', type=str, default=ROOT / 'yolov5s.pt', help='initial weights path')
    parser.add_argument('--cfg', type=str, default='', help='model.yaml path')
    parser.add_argument('--data', type=str, default=ROOT / 'data/coco128.yaml', help='dataset.yaml path')
    parser.add_argument('--hyp', type=str, default=ROOT / 'data/hyps/hyp.scratch-low.yaml', help='hyperparameters path')
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=100, help='total training epochs')
    parser.add_argument('--batch-size', type=int, default=16, help='total batch size for all GPUs, -1 for autobatch')
    parser.add_argument('--imgsz', '--img', '--img-size', type=int, default=640, help='train, val image size (pixels)')
    parser.add_argument('--rect', action='store_true', help='rectangular training')
    parser.add_argument('--resume', nargs='?', const=True, default=False, help='resume most recent training')
    parser.add_argument('--nosave', action='store_true', help='only save final checkpoint')
    parser.add_argument('--noval', action='store_true', help='only validate final epoch')
    parser.add_argument('--noautoanchor', action='store_true', help='disable AutoAnchor')
    parser.add_argument('--noplots', action='store_true', help='save no plot files')
    parser.add_argument('--evolve', type=int, nargs='?', const=300, help='evolve hyperparameters for x generations')
    parser.add_argument('--bucket', type=str, default='', help='gsutil bucket')
    parser.add_argument('--cache', type=str, nargs='?', const='ram', help='image --cache ram/disk')
    parser.add_argument('--image-weights', action='store_true', help='use weighted image selection for training')
    parser.add_argument('--device', default='', help='cuda device, i.e. 0 or 0,1,2,3 or cpu')
    parser.add_argument('--multi-scale', action='store_true', help='vary img-size +/- 50%%')
    parser.add_argument('--single-cls', action='store_true', help='train multi-class data as single-class')
    parser.add_argument('--optimizer', type=str, choices=['SGD', 'Adam', 'AdamW'], default='SGD', help='optimizer')
    parser.add_argument('--sync-bn', action='store_true', help='use SyncBatchNorm, only available in DDP mode')
    parser.add_argument('--workers', type=int, default=8, help='max dataloader workers (per RANK in DDP mode)')
    parser.add_argument('--project', default=ROOT / 'runs/train', help='save to project/name')
    parser.add_argument('--name', default='exp', help='save to project/name')
    parser.add_argument('--exist-ok', action='store_true', help='existing project/name ok, do not increment')
    parser.add_argument('--quad', action='store_true', help='quad dataloader')
    parser.add_argument('--cos-lr', action='store_true', help='cosine LR scheduler')
    parser.add_argument('--label-smoothing', type=float, default=0.0, help='Label smoothing epsilon')
    parser.add_argument('--patience', type=int, default=100, help='EarlyStopping patience (epochs without improvement)')
    parser.add_argument('--freeze', nargs='+', type=int, default=[0], help='Freeze layers: backbone=10, first3=0 1 2')
    parser.add_argument('--save-period', type=int, default=-1, help='Save checkpoint every x epochs (disabled if < 1)')
    parser.add_argument('--seed', type=int, default=0, help='Global training seed')
    parser.add_argument('--local_rank', type=int, default=-1, help='Automatic DDP Multi-GPU argument, do not modify')

    # Logger arguments
    parser.add_argument('--entity', default=None, help='Entity')
    parser.add_argument('--upload_dataset', nargs='?', const=True, default=False, help='Upload data, "val" option')
    parser.add_argument('--bbox_interval', type=int, default=-1, help='Set bounding-box image logging interval')
    parser.add_argument('--artifact_alias', type=str, default='latest', help='Version of dataset artifact to use')

    return parser.parse_known_args()[0] if known else parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: As a side note, you should generally use `sys.executable` instead of `python3.10` or the like when spawning a Python subprocess if you want to make sure that the subprocess will use the same Python interpreter

Comment: My aim here is to get the code to work with a custom python environment, which has other entities tied to it. Hence I want to use the [`train.run()`](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/train.py) function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`argparse.parse_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args) returns an [`argparse.Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) object, which is just a simple "bag of attributes" object. Per the docs:

> This class is deliberately simple, just an object subclass with a readable string representation

You can pass *any* object that has attributes set for each of the CLI arguments for `opt`. For example, any of

```
opt = object()
opt.img = 512
# ...
```

or

```
import argpase
opt = argparse.Namespace(
    img=512,
    # ...
)
```

or

```
import types
opt = types.SimpleNamespace(
    img=512,
    # ...
)
```

would do the trick. Be mindful that many of the CLI arguments have default values that get populated into `opt`, so you will likely need to specify more arguments than what you've provided when using the CLI interface.

Alternatively, you could create a modified version of `parse_opt` that directly interprets you're existing CLI arguments into the same namespace object that gets created when running `train.py`:

```
def parse_opt_modified(raw_args: list[str]) -> argparse.Namespace:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # ....
    return parser.parg_args(raw_args)
```

then in your code, call it as

```
opt = parse_opt_modified(
    [
         '--img',
         'weights/last_yolov5s_custom.pt',
         '--img',
         '512',
         '--batch',
         '14',
         '--epochs',
         '2',
         '--data',
         'neurons.yaml',
         '--weights',
         'yolov5s.pt',
         '--cache',
         'ram,
    ]
)
```

Comment: However there is another way of doing it using [train.run()](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/train.py) `from yolov5 import train; train.run(data='neurons.yaml', imgsz=512, weights='yolov5m.pt', epochs=2, batch=14)`, thanks again!